# Print multidimensional array of chars

Tags: c, arrays, string, output-formatting

I am trying to print the below two dimensional string array in C as below:

```
char text[10][80] = {
    "0", "Zero",
    "1", "One",
    "2", "Two",
    "3", "Three",
    "4", "Four",
};
```

The output should be like this:

```
0 Zero
1 One
2 Two
3 Three 
4 Four
```

I have written the below program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char text[10][80] = {
        "0", "Zero",
        "1", "One",
        "2", "Two",
        "3", "Three",
        "4", "Four",
    };
    int i, j;
    for(i=0; i<6; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<1; j++)
        {
            printf("%s ", text[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It does not provide me the desired output. I have tried several ways, but no luck.

Comment: `for(j=0; j<1; j++)` what's the purpose?

Comment: you need to print array element like text[i][j] in printf statement.

Comment: To create the column space.

Comment: And what is the actual output? What do you think the error might be?

Comment: @Murli I have tried that too. But no good luck :(

Comment: Since you never print a newline, I guess the output is one line; `"0 Zero 1 One 2 Two 3 Three 4 Four"`, right? And please, make it `i < 5`, otherwise you get garbage at the end of the line.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis wrong: https://ideone.com/rQcJlB

Comment: @Idos I think it's not a duplicate

Comment: @Wolf: sorry I misread that. But at least `0 Zero 1 One 2 Two`. I merely wanted to point out that after outputting two items, a newline should be printed.

Comment: FWIW, I don't think this is a duplicate. This is just a tricky way to print a one-dimensional array of fixed length strings. This is not the same as the other question, IMO.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I think that this is not a duplicate, because char arrays are very special in C, for instance the assignment of string literals ***is*** confusing to C novices. I already voted to reopen, you too?

Comment: @Wolf: yes, I voted to reopen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can modify your loop to get desired output -

```
for(i=0; i<9; i=i+2){
    printf("%s %s\n", text[i], text[i+1]);
}
```

This loop will print the contents of array with index `i` and `i+1` in desired format . Like values at index `0` and `1` , `2` and `3`  and so on .

Comment: That's exactly works how I want. Thanks many for the suggestion.

Comment: Why not the stereotypical `i<10` and `i+=2` ? I think some explanatory words could help: the 2D array **formatting above is so misleading**.

Comment: @Wolf I think loop is fairly self explanatory . And besides setting condition to `i<10` would access out of bound index with `text[i+1]` in `printf`.

Comment: @Wolf I don't get what is misleading but I have added explanation regardless.

Comment: not true https://ideone.com/1ikFQP the loop doesn't overflow, because 10 isn't `< 10`. And since the array has 10 elements, it's better to repeat the literal 10.

Comment: @Wolf Yeah I actually missed on that. My bad, I was actually trying to be on a safer side .

Comment: Sorry for bothering, the explanation goes the wrong way. The array has 10 elements and these elements are arrays themselves, the formatting aims to print a 2x5 table. I think the OP is confused about the relation of things looking like arrays and things that really are arrays.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118200/discussion-between-wolf-and-ameycu).

Comment: I tried some explanation with [another approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38571266/2932052) which is of course not as fast as yours ;)

Comment: @Wolf Actually yours is unconventional  approach but intresting :)

Answer (score 2):

Your data is organized as an 10-element array of char arrays each having space for 80 chars (zero terminator char inclusive).<sup>1</sup> The even elements, 0, 2, 4, etc. contain number literals, the odd elements 1, 3, 4, etc. contain the names of these numbers. BTW: 80 chars is a lot of space reserved for such short strings.

The output should be formatted in two columns with the even elements in the first and the odd elements in the second column, each row looks like this:

`number`→`name`↵

As to do this in a loop, I found it interesting<sup>2</sup> to ***select the format parameter*** for `printf` depending on the index `i` being odd or even:<sup>3</sup>

```
#include <stdio.h>

char text[10][80] = {
    "0", "Zero",
    "1", "One",
    "2", "Two",
    "3", "Three",
    "4", "Four",
};

int main(void) {
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
        printf( (i&1) ? "%s\n" : "%s\t", text[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Even though it is often a good idea to write and format code as close as possible to the problem that should by solved, it can sometimes obfuscate what's really going on. This is what the compiler "sees":

```
char text[10][80] = {
    "0",
    "Zero",
    "1",
    "One",
    "2",
    "Two",
    "3",
    "Three",
    "4",
    "Four",
};
```

...which is a convenient short form to initialize char arrays used as strings, it's internally expanded into this

```
char text[10][80] = {
    {'0'},
    {'Z', 'e', 'r', 'o'},
    {'1'},
    {'O', 'n', 'e'},
    {'2'},
    {'T', 'w', 'o'},
    {'3'},
    {'T', 'h', 'r', 'e', 'e'},
    {'4'},
    {'F', 'o', 'u', 'r'},
};
```

The terminating `\0' chars are automatically added since each array that is initialized with fewer values than it has elements is filled up with the default value.

<sup>2</sup> It reflects the given task best as I find. If you are interested in the "fastest" code [ameyCU's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38563052/2932052) seems a good approach.

<sup>3</sup> See this code running in a [live demo](https://ideone.com/BWd19E).

Comment: @Sayeed I hoped it to be more than that, the code is suboptimal, but the explanation should help to better understand the task. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can follow a simple logic, print all `text[i]`s and add a newline if the index is odd number (even iteration), like

```
for(i=0; i<10; i++)
{
        printf("%s\t", text[i]);

    if ( i%2 ) puts("");
}
```

Otherwise, another fancy way of doing this is to insert (*append*) a *tab* or a *newline* into the print statement itself, based on the iteration (index) number, like

```
for(i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    printf("%s%c", text[i], i%2?'\n':'\t');
}
```

Comment: What a creative indentation :) ...seriously: it makes absolutely sense. Maybe you should say a word about `puts("")`

Comment: `printf("%s%c", text[i], i%2?'\n':'\t');`

Comment: @pmg A rather fancy way, let me add that in my answer itself. :)

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your description if you want a two dimensional array of strings or a two dimensional array of chars (hence a one dimensional array of strings). If the first one is true then try:

```
int main()
{
    char *text[10][80] = {
        {"0", "Zero",},
        {"1", "One",},
        {"2", "Two",},
        {"3", "Three",},
        {"4", "Four",},
    };
    int i, j;
    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<2; j++)
        {
            printf("%s ", text[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: What do you mean by "correctness" of an array?

Comment: What you are suggesting is something like `char* text[5][2]` good idea, but not yet written down :)

Comment: concerning the "correctness": `{"0", "Zero"}` initializes an 2-element array of char pointers or a 2-element array of char arrays (of at least size 5).

Comment: @Wolf: `char * text[5][2]` would indeed match the structure of the array in this answer.

Comment: @Wolf : In this case `{"0", "Zero"} ` initializes the first two elements of an array of 80 strings in the fiollowing way: `text[0][0]` to string "0" and `text[0][1]` to string "Zero". Then `{"1", "One",}` initializes `text[1][0]` to string "1" and `text[1][1]` to string "One". My feeling is that this is the solution OP was looking for when asking about multidimensional string array.

Comment: Well, but the OP has `char [10][80]` not `char*[10][80]`, right?

Comment: If you want to enforce the two column structure, maybe `char text[][2][80] = {...` is a better choice.

Comment: Interested removing the downvote from your answer? [Here](https://ideone.com/Fn6S8B) we get an impression of how much space is in use. You do a partial initialization, and the compiler automatically adds the missing initializers with default default values. If you want to show a different but closely related task and solution you are free to do so. *But* you miss to justify the use of so much extra space in your 2D array (and I doubt this to be possible). How helpful is that? Remember that the OP was most probably given just the array posted in the question, and the task was to work with that.

Comment: @Wolf: Don't worry about downvote. To explain myself: OP posted a broken program and it was not evident what he was missing. His question could be a simplified part of a larger task like spelling digits in 80 languages. I have posted one of possibilities how to modify his code  to make it work.  Even if it is not the accepted answer it could be useful to somebody else browsing around.

Comment: @Marian Well, *please do my homework* was the hidden title once again. The OP seemed not really understand the task, maybe not his/her fault. Anyway, have a nice day :)